# Webpack <script src="./main.js"> runs in local browser but not in puppeteer browser

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack, puppeteer

I need my webpack index.html to run the js in the script tag in a puppeteer browser instance. But so far it only runs if I open it directly in my local chrome browser. The code is almost identical with [puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/get-started) and [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) docs, so i guess the error is in my way of implementation.

SOLVED:
changed `await page.setContent(buildHTML, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });` to `await page.goto("file:///Users/user/dev/puppeteer/dist/index.html", { waitUntil: "networkidle0", });`

./dist/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
    <h1>H1</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

./scr/index.js

```js
import _ from "lodash";

function component() {
  console.log("component");
  const element = document.createElement("div");

  element.innerHTML = _.join(["Hello", "webpack"], " ");

  return element;
}

//runs if you open index.html in browser but not if you open with puppeteer
document.body.appendChild(component());
```

./puppeteer.js

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

  const buildHTML = await fs.readFileSync("./dist/index.html", "utf8");

  //logs file content, so path is fine
  console.log(buildHTML);

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  try {
    await page.setContent(buildHTML, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

    //never finds a div because ./scr/index.js doesn't run
    await page.waitForSelector("div");

    await page.screenshot({
      path: `./rendered-img.png`,
      fullPage: true,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw new Error("page.setContent/waitForSelector timed out.");
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

./package.json

```js
{
  "name": "puppeteer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "puppeteer": "^10.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.56.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  }
}
```

./webpack-config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
};
```

Comment: Maye be it has something to do with the (relative) paths. Perhaps you can try changing the current directory to **dist** before launching puppeteer. And then load HTML from **./index.html**

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately